# Google Developer Tools not showing errors properly

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm not sure if it was a Chrome update or what happened, but now Google Chrome Developer is not displaying errors properly.

You'll note it states 1 error in the upper left corner and there is a pink/red line in the Console like errors are usually highlighted in, but it does not tell me what the error is.

[Google Developer Tools Error Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qWpc.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Click "Custom levels" and switch it to defaults.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a Chrome bug. I've been getting the same issue for the last couple of weeks, since about around the release of Chrome v66. Completely frustrating, but it doesn't happen in Firefox, and I've traced the stack through Angular to where the error gets thrown, and it's fine right up until throw. The var containing the error shows the error, but the console doesn't display it except as a blank, thin red line.

Comment: Yup.. that's exactly what I'm seeing.  Thanks for the info as I knew that it was something new.   I had the Custom Levels set fine to display them (thus the reason the red line was even showing).